# Is it possible to add a retry method to axios response inteceptor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, graphql

```
graphqlInstance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  if (response?.data?.errors) {
    const err = response?.data?.errors?.[0];
    const extension = response?.data?.errors?.[0]?.extensions;
    if (extension?.statusCode === 401 || err?.message === "401 : [no body]") {
      // retry
    }
  }
  return response;
});
```

In the response part, I need to call the previous request if the API response returns 401.

Note:

- I'm using graphql which returns a "200 OK" response code for exceptions that's why I m trying to handle the retry method in the success part.

Need to call the previous request if API returns 401.

Answer (score 0):

[Axios Interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) takes two callbacks as its arguments.

1. First callback runs in the success situations, when status code is within 2xx.
2. Second callback runs in the error situations.

I think you should write like this:

```
graphqlInstance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
//Success code
},error => {
    if (error?.config) {
       Axios.request(error?.config);
    }
  }
});
```